# Comprehensions to combine two dicts and create value lists

Tags: python, merge, dictionary-comprehension

I have two dictionaries that are each used to count the number of instances of unique strings in two lists. They look like this except they have thousands of entries:

```
d1 = {'pig':10, 'cow':40, 'sheep':50}
d2 = {'pig':40, 'cow':20, 'sheep':10, 'tiger':30}

d1_total = 100    #sum of the dictionary values
d2_total = 100    #my actual dictionaries have different sums
```

I want a new dictionary to be populated with the keys that appear in both d1 and d2. I want the value of each key to be a list v with the following:

```
v[0] = d2_value/d1_value    #fold change
v[1] = d1_value/d1_total    #fraction of the total count (d1)
v[2] = d2_value/d2_total    #fraction of the total count (d2)
```

So the end result is:

```
d_new = {'pig':[4, 0.1, 0.4], 'cow':[0.5, 0.4, 0.2], 'sheep':'[0.2, 0.5, 0.1]}
```

I wrote the following code, which works, but with the huge size of the dictionaries, it takes way too long to execute:

```
def common_keys(d1, d2, d1_total, d2_total):
    common = {}
    for x, y in d1.iteritems():
        for k, v in d2.iteritems():

            d1_frac = y/d1_total
            d2_frac = v/d2_total
            fold_change = d2_frac/d1_frac

            if x == k:
                common[x] = [fold_change, d1_frac, d2_frac]
    return commmon
```

I feel like I should do this with dictionary comprehensions to increase the speed, but I don't know how to go about gathering the values from both dictionaries, etc... Something like:

```
common = {k:[???, (v/d1_total), (???/d2_total)] for k, v in d1.items() if k in d2.items()}
```

Can you help me write this correctly? Thank you very much for your help. I am finally wrapping my head around dictionary comprehensions but things get confusing when combining dictionaries and modifying the values into a list like this.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a comprehension to increase the speed here.  Personally, I'd avoid it as the list creation gets too jumbled and it becomes harder to read.  What you need is a better *algorithm*.  Specifically, you can do this better by doing a key lookup rather than iterating over `d2` to find the common item:

```
def common_keys(d1, d2, d1_total, d2_total):
    common = {}
    for x, y in d1.iteritems():
        try:
            v = d2[x]
        except KeyError:
            continue

        d1_frac = y/d1_total
        d2_frac = v/d2_total
        fold_change = d2_frac/d1_frac

        common[x] = [fold_change, d1_frac, d2_frac]
    return commmon
```

Doing it this way gets rid of the inner loop which is a huge time-saver.

Comment: This is great, thanks. I knew that a loop within a loop is unnecessary and inefficient but I didn't know any other way to do it. I agree that this structure much more readable than a comprehension.

Comment: When it comes to Python code optimization - I'd have a look at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw5McUt95YdeMlNiX2VSR1lFRHM/view, where you'd see that the first step after profiling to know where your bottlenecks are (p. 14), is as @mgilson suggested - trying to find a better algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

You can take key intersection in Python 3 and do:

```
d_new = {k: [d2[k]/d1[k], d1[k]/d1_total, d2[k]/d2_total] 
                                          for k in d1.keys() & d2.keys()}
```

Take the intersection in Python 2 with `set(d1).intersection(d2)` or `d1.viewkeys() & d2.viewkeys()`.

Also, be mindful of floor division for two integer operands with operator `/` in Python 2.

You could use `d2[k]/float(d1[k]), ...` to avoid a floor division.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional dictionary comprehension.  Iterate through each key in `d1` and check if it is in `d2`

```
d1_total = float(sum(d1.values()))
d2_total = float(sum(d2.values()))
>>> {k: [d2[k] / float(d1[k]), d1[k] / d1_total, d2[k] / d2_total] 
     for k in d1 if k in d2}
{'cow': [0.5, 0.4, 0.2], 'pig': [4.0, 0.1, 0.4], 'sheep': [0.2, 0.5, 0.1]}
```

**TIMINGS**

```
d1 = {n: 'a' for n in range(100000)}
d2 = {n: 'b' for n in range(50000, 150000)}

>>> %timeit [k for k in d1 if k in d2]
100 loops, best of 3: 10.1 ms per loop

>>> %timeit [k for k in d1.viewkeys() & d2.viewkeys()]
100 loops, best of 3: 10.5 ms per loop
```

The timings should be similar.